# How to store a tuple of floats into a file, open and read it to extract the mean per column?

Tags: python, file, tuples, mean

I am computing the following scores iteratively which generates a new set of the following scores
in each iteration:

`add_score, keep_score, del_score = get_corpus_sari_operation_scores(sources, prediction, references)`

I first want to store them into a file, currently I add them as a tuple to a list and store the list (~9000 lines) in a file:

```
stat = add_score, keep_score, del_score
stats.append(stat)
f = open("./resources/outputs/generate/stats.txt", "w")
    for stat in stats:
        print('stat type', type(stat))
        f.write(stat)
        f.write("\n")
    f.close()
```

the values in the stats.txt file look as follows:

```
(2.0, 28.25187646117879,  69.96132803170339) 
(0.0, 23.357228195937875, 50.342178147056195) 
(1.7241379310344827, 25.888065422949147, 40.21927767354597) 
(0.0, 47.375201191814064, 16.312725613543307) 
(1.7857142857142856, 14.565677966101696, 54.81682319618366) 
(0.0, 63.79656946826759, 9.200422070604626)
```

What i wanna do is to reaccess this data in another method and read from the file. My goal is to calculate the **mean per colum**, thus `mean(add_score)`, `mean(keep_score)`, `mean(del_score)`.

However, the values of the file get accessed as tuples/Series.
I tried to convert the tuples into a dataframe to then use the `mean()` method per colum but I struggle with the conversion of the tuples to a dataframe.

Does anyone have a better idea on how to handle this data? I wondering if there is a better way to store all scoring results in one file and then calculate the mean per each column.

Comment: Why not saving your data as a CSV file then access it from another method/process and handle it directly with pandas ? Even better why not using a database for this kind of tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... struggle with the conversion of the tuples to a dataframe.

You are complaining that the file format is inconvenient.
So use the familiar [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
format instead.

```
import csv

with open("resources/outputs/generate/stats.txt", "w") as f:
    sheet = csv.writer(f)
    sheet.writerow(('add', 'keep', 'del'))
    for stat in stats:
        sheet.writerow(stat)
```

Then later a simple `df = pd.read_csv('stats.txt')` should suffice.

---

Alternatively, assign `df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=('add', 'keep', 'del'))` and then `df.write_csv('stats.txt')` instead
of creating a CSV Writer or DictWriter.

Comment: I implemented your solution and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, the solution of J_H worked like a marvel. I implemented:

```
with open("resources/outputs/generate/stats.txt", "w", newline='') as f:
        sheet = csv.writer(f)
        sheet.writerow(('add', 'keep', 'del'))
        for stat in stats:
            sheet.writerow(stat)
```

and added `newline=''` to avoid printing empty rows.

I then accessed my data and calculated my means without the dtype as follows:

`avg_add= df['add'].mean().item()`